# Google apps script - Get row number of a cell containing specific value

Tags: google-apps-script

How could I get the row number of a cell which contains a specified value.

In the code below I would like to get the row number of the cell containing number 5 in the column H.

```
function doGet(e){

   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("........sheet id........");
   var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");  


  var containingValue = 5;
  var range = sheet.getRange("H1:H"); 


 // [code to get valuie of Row]


  sheet.getRange(Row, 12).setValue("A text");
}
```

I would like to get the value of the row and update another cell in that row.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a for loop:

```
// get the values in an array
var values = range.getValues();

// examin the values in the array
var i = []; 
for (var y = 0; y < values.length; y++) {
   if(values[y] == containingValue){
      i.push(y);
   }
}
// translate the indices into rows
var Row = Number(i)+Number(range.getRow());
```

Comment: Tried this code but it is returning the row 51 whereas the value present is present in row 6.

Answer (score 1):

You can now get the value of the row without coding the loop yourself.

If you are sure that there is only one cell having the value *containingValue*, this [line](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getRow()) will do the job:

```
let Row = range.createTextFinder(containingValue).matchEntireCell(true).findNext().getRow();
```